# Making a Binary Table in Python Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to convert this to a binary table wherein the index values of the binary table are the order IDs and the column values of the binary table are bread,cheese,eggs,flour,and jam. The values of the binary table are either 1 or 0: 1 if that specific order contains the product and 0 if it doesn't.

```
OrderNum
1000                   [eggs]
1001                  [bread]
1002     [eggs, bread, flour]
1003       [eggs, jam, bread]
1004                   [eggs]
                ...          
1495     [eggs, bread, flour]
1496    [eggs, cheese, bread]
1497                    [jam]
1498                  [bread]
1499            [eggs, bread]
Length: 500, dtype: object
```

It should look like this:

```
        bread cheese eggs flour jam
1000      0     0     1    0    0     
1001      1     0     0    0    0
1002      1     0     1    1    0  
1003      1     0     1    0    1          
1004      0     0     1    0    0
                  ...          
1495      1     0     1    1    0     
1496      1     1     1    0    0    
1497      0     0     0    0    1                    
1498      1     0     0    0    0                  
1499      1     0     1    0    0
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
pd.get_dummies(df['OrderNum'].explode()).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Answer (score -1):

- simulated the data, having a **list** of items against an **OrderNo**
- use a **dict** comprehension to turn into a **series**.  Then it's simple `isna()` logic

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

items = ["bread","cheese","eggs","flour","jam"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"OrderNo":range(1000,1020), 
              "Items":[np.unique(np.random.choice(items, 8)) for x in range(20)]})

df.join(df["Items"].apply(lambda l: ~pd.Series({i:i for i in l}).isna()).fillna(False).astype(int))
```

| OrderNo | Items | bread | cheese | eggs | flour | jam |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1001 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1002 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1003 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1004 | ['cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1005 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1006 | ['bread' 'eggs' 'jam'] | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1007 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1008 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1009 | ['bread' 'eggs' 'flour'] | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1010 | ['cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1011 | ['cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1012 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1013 | ['bread' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1014 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1015 | ['bread' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1016 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1017 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1018 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'eggs' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1019 | ['bread' 'cheese' 'flour' 'jam'] | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |